# Android sqlite Query with AND

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I wanted to ask how do you make a query like :

```
select * from table where id = 1 AND year = 1999
```

with the command query of sqlite in Android?
Thanks in advance

Comment: ... what is this question about? You already have the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add "AND" to the 3rd parameter (`String selection`):

```
database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2},
               COLUMN_1 + " = ? AND " + COLUMN_2 + " = ? ", new String[]{value1, value2}, null, null, null);
```

In your case, `COLUMN_1` is `id`, `COLUMN_2` is `year`, `value1` is `"1"`, `value2` is `"1999"`.

Comment: I was adding the same.

Comment: thanks, I have written the query in this way Cursor mCursor =  database.query(HOUR_DATABASE_TABLE,new String[] { ID, WEEK_ID, YEAR, HOUR, MOUNTH, OVERTIME }, WEEK_ID + "=? AND" + YEAR+"=?",new String[]{Integer.toString(week),Integer.toString(year)} , null, null, null);' but returns this exception castException Boolean -> String

Comment: Add a space after the `AND` and before the `"`

Comment: thank you very much, it was a success